How to implement validation only once for properties and commands?
In WPF, I am thinking how to implement validation, only once, and to be use for commands and for the view model to can warn to the user the problem.
For me, perhaps I am wrong, but when a view model validates a property, it is validated according to the command that I want to execute.
For that, it is the command who determinates the logic of the validation, same logic that the view model will have to use to validate the property.
So I would like to have a class to validate the a data, perhaps using a validation rule, that it will be used in the CanExecute method of the command and it will he use by the view model to validate the property.
I would like to use a class for the command, because I think the logic of the command shouldn't be in the view model, the view model only has to expose the data the view needs, and perhaps adapt the data from the command to a format that is better for the view.
And the view model, that uses the validation class to validate the proerty and uses the command to perform the action.
According to this, supose I have a view model with an email property and a command that is SaveEmail. The for simplify, it is very easy, just check if an string has at least one "@".
    public class EmailValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            if(value.ToString().Contains("@"))
            {
                return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
            }
    
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Email format is invalid.");
            }
        }
    }

    public interface ISaveEmailCommand()
    {
        public Task Execute();
    
    
        public void CanExecute();
    }

    public class SaveEmailCommand : ISaveEmailCommand
    {
        public async Task Execute(string Email)
        {
            //code to save email in the database
        }
    
    
        public bool CanExecute(string Email)
        {
            //Use in some way EmailValidationRule, or the class to validate
        }
    }

    //To simplify code, I use CommunityToolkit.MVVM
    public partial class EmailViewModel : ObservableCollection
    {
        ISaveEmailCommand _saveEmailCommand;
    
    
        //The command is injected in the view model.
        public EmailViewModel(ISaveEmailCommand paramSaveEmailCommand)
        {
            _saveEmailCommand = paramSaveEmailCommand;
        }
    
    
    
    
    
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string _email;
    
    
        [RelayCommand]
        [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(SaveEmailCanExecute))]
        public async Task SaveEmail()
        {
            _saveEmailCommand.Execute(Email);
        }
    
    
        private bool SaveEmailcanExecute()
        {
            return _saveEmailCommand.CanExecute(Email);
        }
    }

      <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                         Padding="0,5"
                         Width="255"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Email"
                                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <validation:EmailValidationRule />
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>

But I see some drowbacks in this solution. Although it is not directly related with the validation of the property, but more about when to enable or disable the command.
One reason to disable the command is because the property (the data that it needs), is incorrect. But other reason could be for external reasons.
For example, perhaps there are some conditions that could make the command to be disabled and it is not responsability of the command. Supose that in the UI the is a checkbox that the user can check or not to disabled the action. I guess the command shouldn't know that, it is more a view model concern to disable the command. In this case, I would have the logic to enable or not the command in two places, in the validation rule and also in the view model to know if the checkbox is checked or not.
So in summary, I would like to know how could I have a command in a separate class, the view model and a way to implement the logic to validate the property and also the way to enable or disable  the command because the data is incorrect or because of external conditions (user disable the command).
Thanks.

You should move the property validation completely to the view model by implementing INotifyDataErorInfo. This way you can directly access the property validation results. Your command can simply call EmailViewModel.HasPropertyErrors(nameof(Email)) to know whether the property value is valid and the command can execute. For an example, see How to add validation to view model properties or how to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo.

I can post another example if it's not clear how the command should interact with the EmailViewModel if you want me to. You should be able to completely copy the INotifyDataErrorInfo implementation. Just remove the example properties that show how to invoke the validation. You can even reuse your ValidationRule.

It "depends"; mostly on the user and their mental model. You can have "field edits" (while entering). Or "record" edits (when saving). Or a combination. Are there "modes"; as in (heads down) "data entry mode" (add only). Is it real time or batched? Is there an "update" mode? Are we using pessimistic or optimistic locking? You sit with the user ... then design.

@BionicCode Perhaps your solution is to pass the view model to the command, at least i have seen some solutions in this way, but then the command is coupled to the view model. My Idea it is to find some way to have an independent command that could be used by different view models, if it would be needed.

Not if you use a reusable ICommand implementation like this [RelayCommand](Relaying Command Logic). This commands accepts delegates for ICommand.Execute and ICommand.CanExecute. If these delegates were defined in the view model class, then you can directly query properties of the view model. This way your command can be reused with any context.

Your example looks like it uses MVVM Tool Kit. It also generates a RelayCommand so you don't have to change much except for moving the validation to the EmailViewModel. Let me post a small example

But why is your EmailViewModel extzending ObservableCollection? A typo?

@ÁlvaroGarcía I could be wrong but I don't know of any way to do what I think you want - allow external classes to directly alter the enabled state of a command - without something like the ResponsiveCommand class in my answer where you just manually set its IsEnabled state as needed.

This question highlights the need for a generalized view model-level data binding framework - which is possible to make, but requires very careful use of PropertyChanged subscriptions and un-subscriptions, and a homegrown weak even pattern, all of which are well beyond the scope of what's practical in a single answer.
Barring that, the solution will by necessity be somewhat ad hoc. The good news is that virtually all the logic can be done view mode-side. The bad news is that, without the aforementioned binding framework, you're looking at a fair amount of scaffolding and potentially some procedural code that doesn't necessarily scale super well.
Note - the question wasn't originally tagged as specific to MVVM Community Toolkit, even though the OP indicates in the code example that they are using it, so this is a self-contained solution that relies on no specific toolkits. BionicCode's solution looks like it would work well for Toolkit users.
Let's start with the ICommand implementation, which you're gonna need no matter what, and which I'm gonna call ResponsiveCommand.
ResponsiveCommand
public class ResponsiveCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;
    private readonly INotifyDataErrorInfo? _validationSource;
    private readonly string? _validationProperty;

    public ResponsiveCommand(
        Action action,

        // Optional - the view model whose validation state to tie to
        // the command enabled state. **Important** to avoid
        // memory leaks, this needs to be the same instance
        // that owns the command. If null, the enabled state
        // must be manually set with the IsEnabled property.
        INotifyDataErrorInfo? validationSource = null,

        // Optional - the name of the property whose validation
        // state to tie to the command's enabled state. If null,
        // any validation errors on the validationSource will
        // disable the command.
        string? validationProperty = null)
    {
        _action = action;
        _validationSource = validationSource;
        _validationProperty = validationProperty;

        if (_validationSource != null)
        {
            // It's ok to subscribe here without a corresponding
            // unsubscribe **as long as** the validation source 
            // also owns the command. That restriction ensures 
            // the lifecycle of the view model is the same as the
            // command.
            _validationSource.ErrorsChanged += this.OnValidationErrorsChanged;
            UpdateValidationState(_validationProperty);
        }
    }
  
    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;

    private bool _isEnabled = true;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get => _isEnabled;
        set
        {
            if (_isEnabled != value)
                return;
            _isEnabled = value;
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
    {
        return _isEnabled;
    }

    public void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        _action?.Invoke();
    }

    private void OnValidationErrorsChanged(
        object? sender,
        DataErrorsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateValidationState(e.PropertyName);
    }

    private void UpdateValidationState(string? property)
    {
        if (_validationProperty == null)
        {
            this.IsEnabled = !this._validationSource!.HasErrors;
            return;
        }

        if (property != _validationProperty)
            return;

        var errors = _validationSource!.GetErrors(this._validationProperty);
        this.IsEnabled = !errors.Cast<object>().Any();
    }
}

This is a pretty powerful implementation of ICommand because it gives you two possible ways of tying a button's enabled state to the validation state of a view model property: through INotifyDataErrorInfo, or manually through its IsEnabled property.
The INotifyDataErrorInfo Approach and Example Implementation
I'll start with the INotifyDataErrorInfo approach because no matter which approach is used to control the command's enabled state, it's always a great idea for a view model that owns any bound properties to also implement INotifyDataErrorInfo. This will allow you to not just disable the button via ResponsiveCommand, but also to provide visual feedback on the input field itself. Here's a sample implementation of a view model that also implements INotifyDataErrorInfo, which I'll call ResponsiveViewModel:
public class ResponsiveViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs>? ErrorsChanged;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public bool HasErrors => this._propertyErrors.Any();

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string? propertyName)
    {
        if (_propertyErrors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var error))
            // Though INotifyDataErrorInfo supports multiple simultaneous
            // errors, for example's sake it's simpler to demonstrate
            // a single error at a time per property.
            return new string[] { error };
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(
        bool validates = false,
        [CallerMemberName] string property = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));

        if (!validates)
             return;
        
        _propertyErrors.TryGetValue(property, out var oldError);

        string? newError = ValidateProperty(property);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newError))
            _propertyErrors.Remove(property);
        else
            _propertyErrors[property] = newError;

        if (newError != oldError)
        {
            ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(
                this, 
                new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    protected virtual string ValidateProperty(string property)
    {
        return null;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> _propertyErrors = 
        new Dictionary<string, string>();
}

And here's your EmailViewModel, now subclassed from ResponsiveViewModel and utilizing the ResponsiveCommand we defined above:
public class EmailViewModel : ResponsiveViewModel
{
    #region ICommand Submit Command
    private ResponsiveCommand? _SubmitCommand;
    public ICommand SubmitCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _SubmitCommand ?? (_SubmitCommand = new ResponsiveCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    // ...
                },
                this,
                nameof(Email)));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region string Email property
    private string? _email;
    public string? Email
    {
        get
        {
            return _email;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_email == value)
                return;
            _email = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(true);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    protected override string? ValidateProperty(string property)
    {
        // If concerned about the number of properties
        // to validate, a static Dictionary of validation
        // delegates, keyed with the property name, would
        // work too.
        switch (property)
        {
            case nameof(Email):
                // validate email here instead of using
                // a ValidationRule; return null if fine
                // otherwise, provide the error message
                if (this.Email?.Contains('@') == false)
                     return "Invalid email format.";
                return null;
            default:
                return base.ValidateProperty(property);
        }
    }
}

Your EmailViewModel now handles its own property validation, which is far preferable to using a ValidationRule which is a WPF-specific type and doesn't port to other platforms. Overriding ValidateProperty here is a clean way of doing this, as our OnPropertyChanged implementation will invoke this automatically as properties change. There are of course other approaches, but this is about as close as you can get to being able to do property validation as a matter of course with minimal scaffolding.
The other thing this does is instantiate the ResponsiveCommand with this as the validation source. If you look at the ResponsiveCommand implementation, you'll see that the command will consequently start listening for INotifyDataErrorInfo.ErrorsChanged and update its enabled state as needed. Any bound button will therefore likewise have its enabled state tied to the validation of the email property.
Important - The biggest, if not only drawback to this approach is that the validating view model must own the ResponsiveCommand instance, because we never unsubscribe from ErrorsChanged. Thus, memory leaks will occur if the validation source outlives the owner of the ResponsiveCommand. Unless some careful work is done to ensure de-subscription is performed when FrameworkElements are unloaded, a second approach is needed.
Manually Setting IsEnabled
This is simple enough to understand - the view model that owns the Email property simply needs to update the IsEnabled state on the command, like so:
    #region string Email property
    private string? _email;
    public string? Email
    {
        get
        {
            return _email;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_email == value)
                return;
            _email = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            SubmitCommandOwner.SubmitCommand.IsEnabled =
                this.GetErrors(nameof(Email))?.Cast<object>()?.Any();
        }
    }
    #endregion

Easy enough, except depending on your view model hierarchy, the validated property owner and the SubmitCommand owner might be completely different and unaware of each other.  This is where a generalized view model-level binding framework - wherein someone who has access to both instances can bind the command's IsEnabled state to the validation state of Email subscribes to the relevant events and keeps the states in sync - would be helpful.
The other reason it's less than ideal is that we have the property definition actively changing the enabled state of the command, rather than the command asking the property for its validation state. It's preferable (at least in my view) to keep the property setter as clean as possible, and keep the logic for a command's enabled state with the command.
In any event, as you can no doubt see these are but two possible ways of accomplishing what you want. Over time you'll find the best balanced approach for your application.

The idea is to move data validation to your view model classes by implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo. To further simplify the logic and to avoid the dependency from ICommand implementation to the owner that also provides the context for the ICommand.CanExecute you should also use a reusable ICommand implementation.
Because you are using the MVVM Community Toolkit, the following example is implemented using that library.
For a custom implementation of INotifyDataErrorInfo you can see How to add validation to view model properties or how to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo.
The Community Toolkit provides its own RelayCommand (a reusable ICommand implementation) that you can use, either directly as instantiated type or via the RelayCommand attribute (code generation).
To manually implement a RelayCommand you can follow the Microsoft example: Microsoft learn: Relaying Command Logic.
A small note on your current design: from a design perspective it should be noted that data persistence is handled by the application model. In your case, the actual save operation must be implemented in a model class. This class should be passed to the EmailViewModel constructor or private property (or the constructor/property of your ISaveEmailCommand implementation) so that the EmailViewModel (or the ISaveEmailCommand) can use the model's API to save email addresses.
When following common C# design practices, then we shouldn't define public fields. _email must be private.
Now, the Community Toolkit provides the ObservableValidator class that extends the ObservableObject class. It adds a default implementation of INotifyDataErrorInfo and an API around data validation that you can use, like in the example below.
See Microsoft learn: ObservableValidator.
The example uses the following attributes:

a variety of ValidationAttribute attributes to enable attribute based property validation to tell the ObservableValidator which properties we like to validate and how we like them to be validated. These attributes allow to define basic validation rules like MaxLenght. For example, the CustomValidation attribute is used to provide a custom validation method or a validation provider like a custom validator class.
See ValidationAttribute in the "Derived" section to learn about available .NET attributes of which all are supported by the OberservableValidator.

the NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor attribute to tell the ObservableValidator that the specified ICommand.CanExecute must be executed when the decorated property changes. This is necessary as the RelayCommand that the Community Toolkit ships does not use the CommandManger to automatically raises the ICommand.CanExecuteCHanged event to trigger the invocation of the ICommand.CanExecute method.

the NotifyDataErrorInfo attribute to decorate the properties that must participate in the WPF INotifyDataErrorInfo validation infrastructure.


Your refactored example will could look as follows:
EmailValidator.cs
First, you need to replace the ValidationRule or refactor it. This is because the ObservableValidator uses the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult (and not the System.Windows.Controls.ValidationResult).
public class EmailValidator
{
  public static System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult Validate(string email)
  {
    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email) && email.Contains("@")
      ? System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult.Success
      : new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult("Email format is invalid.");
  }
}

EmailViewModel.cs
public partial class EmailViewModel : ObservableValidator
{
  public EmailViewModel()
  {
    // Uncomment the following line if you wish to perform an initial validation.
    // This can be useful if the type is instantiated and configured by the caller 
    // and the provided data is the result of collected user input.
    // However, you may want to consider to separate UI input data validation 
    // and internal data validation.
    // You don't want to show visual feedback for internal data errors. 
    // Instead, you would usually throw an exception.
    //ValidateAllProperties(); // Call ObservableValidator API to force validation of all properties
  }

  [ObservableProperty] // Property must participate in the INotifyPropertyChanged infrastructure
  [NotifyDataErrorInfo] // Property must participate in the INotifyDataErrorInfo infrastructure
  [Required] // A ValidationAttribute
  [CustomValidation(typeof(EmailValidator), nameof(EmailValidator.Validate))] // Another ValidationAttribute that specifies a custom validation method
  [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(this.SaveEmailCommand))] // Tell the ObservableObject to raise the IRelaCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged event
  private string? _email;

  [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanExecuteSaveEmailCommand))]
  private async Task SaveEmailAsync()
  {
    // TODO::Perfrom save operation
  }

  private bool CanExecuteSaveEmailCommand()
  {
    // Use ObservableValidator.HasErrors property to check if any property has errors
    bool hasAnyPropertyValidationErrors = this.HasErrors;

    // Use INotifyDataErrorInfo.GetErrors method to check if a particular property has errors
    bool isEmailValid = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Email) 
      && !GetErrors(nameof(this.Email)).Any();

    // Use the appropriate condition
    return isEmailValid;
  }
}

Finally enable INotifyPropertyChanged support in the view. This will enable WPF to display your error message and to provide other visual error feedback like a red box around the invalid input element. To prepare the view we have to

enable validation error reporting of the binding engine by setting the Binding.ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors property of every Binding that has a validated property as source to true
provide a custom validation error template (optional)

MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxValidationErrorTemplate">
      <StackPanel>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                BorderThickness="1">

          <!-- The placeholder for the TextBox -->
          <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
        </Border>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding /ErrorContent}"
                   Background="White"
                   Foreground="Red"
                   Padding="4" />
      </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Window.DataContext>
    <EmailViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
        
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Save"
            Command="{Binding SaveEmailCommand}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Email, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxValidationErrorTemplate}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>


This looks like some very good use of the MVVM toolkit's capabilities but how would it work if something outside EmailViewModel wanted/needed to disable the command? The OP was talking about a check box for example. That's why I focused a fair amount on a custom ICommand implementation that allowed for manual enabling/disabling. Maybe EmailViewModel could expose a separate public property for this purpose which the validation routine could also check? Basically a "force invalid" mechanism.

You usually bind the CheckBox.IsChecked to a property in view model class. Then the view model class can validate the current state including that property. The ICommand can check that state as usual. And if that property is defined in a different class than the ICommand, then you probably have room to improve your class design. Then the ICommand or the property is probably defined in the wrong data context. Or the class that defines the command simply has a dependency on the class that defines the property. It really depends on the scenario whether that's acceptable or a design flaw.

"Maybe EmailViewModel could expose a separate public property for this purpose which the validation routine could also check? Basically a "force invalid" mechanism" - In my opinion, the ICommand has the dependency on the external state and not the other way around. The other class should not know about the details of the command and e.g. directly inform the owner of the ICommand about all relevant changes. Instead, the owner of the ICommand would observe its dependency to track the dependency's state and call ICommand.CanExecute when appropriate (e.g. from an event handler).

I think the problem is not complex and rather trivial to solve if you follow common design principles. I believe >80% of all solutions that solve a rather trivial problem and are extraordinarily complex are the result of compensating bad design choices. I would rather refactor my code before I implement overly complex classes that are difficult and unintuitive to use and to maintain. I believe the "80%" number is an optimistic estimate.

"And if that property is defined in a different class than the ICommand, then you probably have room to improve your class design." You're not wrong, but I think that's the scenario the OP is asking about. And I have found myself there plenty of times. Say a form VM has a submit command and several child VMs with their own views. If any one of the children is invalid you want the submit button to be disabled, but child VM prop changes won't trigger a validation update on the parent. You'd almost want a multibinding-like mechanism between the parent command enable state and the childrens'.

Thank you for the more concrete example. The solution is pretty straight forward if you chose composition to design the type hierarchy. This top-level form VM will manage a set of child VMs. Each child VM implements INotifyDataErrorInfo to perform data input validation of its own data context. Then the parent form VM simply observes each VM's INotifyDataErrorInfo.ErrorsChanged event where the event handler calls INotifyDataErroInfo.HasErrors on the sender to evaluate the new state.

The form's VM submit ICommand is now invalidated so that it raises the CanExecuteChanged event which in turn causes the Button to call CanExecute to disable or enable itself. The advantage is that the parent VM can manage the error state by strictly depending on the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface. It does not have to know any implementation details about its child view model classes.

Gotcha, that makes sense. Then this is a very good solution for the MVVM toolkit users.
